# why xcopy creates another new folder using batch file

Tags: batch-file, xcopy

I have created a simple batch script that only copies pdf file in the server. Copied file will be stored in a folder in desktop.

But after copying there is a "New Folder" created. Why is this happening?

this is my script :

```
:MENU1
set /p code=Input Folder Code:
if %code%==0 goto MENU1
goto CHECK1

:CHECK1
if exist "%sample2020%\%code%\STANDARD\DATA\PLAN\%code%WAB.pdf goto COPYFILE
if not exist else goto ERROR

:COPYFILE
xcopy "%sample2020%\%code%\STANDARD\DATA\PLAN\%code%WAB.pdf" "%HOMEPATH%\Desktop\2. FILES\%code%\DOCUMENTS\" /D /E /C /I /Y /H

start "" "%HOMEPATH%\Desktop\2. FILES\%code%\DOCUMENTS\"
goto MENU1

:ERROR
echo.
echo PK file cannot find....
PAUSE
start "" "%HOMEPATH%\Desktop\2. FILES\%code%\DOCUMENTS\"
```

this is the actual image of copied files ... as you can see it has a New Folder..
[image]

Comment: Open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/), run `if /?` and read the output help. `if not exist else goto ERROR`  is not of correct syntax. It can be replaced by just `goto ERROR`.

Comment: I recommend further to replace `if %code%==0 goto MENU1` by `if defined code if "%code:"=%" == "0" goto MENU1` for more safety against wrong user input by mistake. See the answer on [How to stop Windows command interpreter from quitting batch file execution on an incorrect user input?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49834019/3074564)

Comment: The only command creating a folder is `xcopy` and that does not create a `New folder`. But the batch is not a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We don't know how the environment variable `sample2020` is defined and we don't know what the user of this batch file enters. Why do yo use `xcopy.exe` instead of newer `robocopy.exe`? Why do you use `xcopy` option `/D`. Why do you use `xcopy` option `/E` to copy also empty directories if you want to copy only a PDF file. Why do you not use `copy` to copy a single PDF file?

Comment: @Mofi I solved it! I just remove the option `/D` and `/E`.

Answer (score 0):

The "New folder" dosen't seem to be created by `xcopy`. Both folders Modification Date is different. Here your switches and other commands don't create any kind of directories. So it might be create by a different application.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I just remove the option `/D` and `E`. Now the New Folder gone..